# Jenkins error Unable to produce a script file

Tags: jenkins

I am getting the following error while trying to build an application.
It worked properly from long time, recently it stopped the build process and throws the error. The configuration of the build uses slave node, In google many suggested that the issue may related to the Java version issues in slave node and the selected version in jenkings configuration section.

```
FATAL: Unable to produce a script file
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temp file on 
/scratch/jenkins/workspace/
at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:1223)
at     hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.createScriptFile(CommandInterpreter.java:115)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:75)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:60)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1593)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:247)
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: remote file operation failed: 
/scratch/jenkins/workspace/ERT_PC_CF7 at 
hudson.remoting.Channel@1f9efe8:build- linux-1
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:901)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:878)
at hudson.FilePath.createTextTempFile(FilePath.java:1200)
... 12 more
Caused by: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to create a temporary directory     in /tmp
at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1212)
at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1200)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2393)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read-only file system
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.checkAndCreate(File.java:1717)
at java.io.File.createTempFile0(File.java:1738)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1815)
at hudson.FilePath$14.invoke(FilePath.java:1210)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a permission issue. The issue has been resolved by rebooting the slave nodes as the whole file system in slave node went into read mode, even the root user gets exception with touch command on the directory /scratch/jenkins/workspace/ .